# How can I make the SCNCamera that i instantiated zoom into only nodes that i want in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit

Pretend i have 3 nodes in total. One of the nodes is a large SCNShere and i put the camera inside this sphere and make the sphere double sided with a textured image. I then put in two smaller spheres next to each other in the center inside this sphere. I also allowCameraControl. I want to be able to zoom into these two smaller spheres without zooming into the larger sphere and messing up the detail on that sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put limits on the camera that's automatically created with `allowCameraControl`. You'll have to do your own camera management, using your own gesture recognizers.

Another solution would be to rethink your approach to the background image. Instead of using a sky sphere for the background (which is what it sounds like you're doing), use a skybox, or cube map. You can supply a cube map through the scene's `background` property. The [SCNMaterial documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents) explains the options for supply a cube map.

Hmm, I wonder what would happen if you use the large sphere's textured image/material as the scene's `background`, instead of putting it on an enclosing sphere?

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of using an image as the background but there are two problems. One is i looked on the web for ways to make an image the background and none of them work. Two I want the background to have depth so in order to go on that idea I need to find a way to zoom into the background and have the image pan in the opposite direction that I drag.

Comment: That means you'll have to write your camera control. You'll need to handle the gesture recognizers, and restrict how far the camera can move/zoom/pan.

Comment: do you know how to disable the drag gesture that you can activate by using 2 fingers and swipe? If you know how to do that then it would be super helpful. I tried

Comment: i tried //var globalPanRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(pointOfViewNode.camera.dragObject(_:)))
        //sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(globalPanRecognizer)

Comment: I don't think you'll succeed by selectively fighting/disabling pieces of the automatic camera. Write your own gesture handlers, and do the whole thing yourself. There are tons of questions/answers on camera manipulation to get you started.